# A tricky problem of Image space and null space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V $ be a finite dimensional vector space and Let $T:V \to V $ be a linear transformation. If $\operatorname{rank} (T)=\operatorname{rank} (T^2)$, prove that $R (T)\cap N (T)={0} $.

MY TRY:

By rank-nullity theorem  $\dim R (T)+ \dim N (T) =\dim V $ and $\dim R (T^2)+ \dim N (T^2)=\dim V$, from the given condition we get $\dim N (T)=\dim N (T^2) $, also $N (T)\subset N (T^2) $. So we get $N (T)=N (T^2) $. If I prove $R (T)\cap N (T^2) ={0} $, then the problem is solved, but I'm stuck  here, I can't prove it... Is there any way to get the desired proof?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146540/let-f-v-n-to-v-n-be-an-endomorphism-prove-textdim-textkerf-cap-tex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v\in N(T)\cap R(T)$. Since $v\in R(T)$, $v=T(w)$ for some $w\in V$. But then$$T^2(w)=T(v)=0,$$since $v\in N(T)$. So, $w\in\ker T^2$, but $\ker T^2=\ker T$ (I will prove it), and therefore $v=T(w)=0$. This proves that $N(T)\cap R(T)=\{0\}$.

The reason why $\ker T=\ker T^2$ is because $\ker T\subset\ker T^2$ and because it follows from the rank-nullity theorem and from the fact that $R(T)$ and $R(T^2)$ have the same dimensions that $\ker T$ and $\ker T^2$ have the same dimensions. Therefore, they are equal.

Comment: Doesn't $v\in R(T)$ imply that $v = T^t(w)$? $R$ is the row space which is the image of $T^t$, yes?

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda I wrote what I wrote assuming that $R(T)$ was the image of $T$. If it's not, the I shall delete my answer.

Comment: No, $R $ means the image space of $T $

Comment: @SubhajitSaha So, I did not waste my time. :-)

Comment: @SubhajitSaha Then you may wish to fix the title, the word "row space" is misleading since it plays no part in the problem.

Comment: @jose carlos santos,thanks then $w $ belongs to null space of $T $ and v becomes 0 vector...I had to solve it as Bernard gave me the hint of this procedure

Comment: @Taisuke Yasuda sorry to make your confusion, I apologies. ..I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Prove directly that $R(t)\cap N(T)=\{0\}$. For this consider an element $u=T(v)$ for some $v\in V$, and write that $T(u)=0$. What can you say for $v$?

Comment: $v$ belongs to $N (T^2) $

Comment: Yes. Hence it belongs to …

Comment: then$v $ belongs to $N (T) $ and u becomes 0,So we get no intersecting vector of $N (T) $ and $R (T) $ except 0

Comment: I didn't get your hint at the 1st time,I need more study☺